# Копирование указателей из одного std::map в другой

Tags: c++, map

Мне нужно скопировать данные из одного std::map в другой std::map, при условии что эти данные выражены в виде указателей. То есть с помощью оператора присваивания эти данные не копируются, копируются лишь адреса.
Вот конкретный пример :

```
std::map<String, Animation*> listOfAnimations;

listOfAnimations = OtherlistOfAnimations; // Так не работает
```

Comment: У вас в мапе хранятся именно объекты `Animation`, или его наследники тоже?

Comment: именно объекты Animation

Comment: Тогда есть какие-то причины не использовать просто `std::map<String, Animation>`.

Comment: К сожалению есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в `map`е хранятся именно объекты `Animation`, а не его наследники, тогда можно сделать так:

```
std::map<String, Animation*> listOfAnimations = OtherlistOfAnimations;

for (auto &it : listOfAnimations)
    it.second = new Animation(*it.second);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если задача не учебная, то для хранения в структурах указателей удобнее использовать [бустовскую билиотеку](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). Там реализовано копирование `map` с копированием объектов. Ну и, кстати, уничтожение объектов при уничтожении контейнера автоматическое.